# Error when hooking a function, "Stack around the variable x was corrupted."? C++

Tags: c++, memory, hook

I'm trying to hook a function on x64 application. Here's my code:

```
int __stdcall nRecv(SOCKET s, char* buf, int len, int flags)
{
    Log("Receving!");
    return 0;
}

BOOL HookFunction(LPCWSTR moduleName, LPCSTR funcName, LPVOID pDestination)
{
    BYTE stub[6] = { 0xe9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc3 };
    DWORD pProtection;

    DWORD pSource = (DWORD)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(moduleName), funcName);


    LPVOID pTrampoline = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 6 + sizeof(stub), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)pSource, 6, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &pProtection);


    CopyMemory(stub + 1, &pDestination, 4);

    CopyMemory((LPVOID)((DWORD_PTR)pTrampoline), &pSource, 6);
    CopyMemory((LPVOID)((DWORD_PTR)pTrampoline + 6), stub, sizeof(stub));


    CopyMemory(stub + 1, &pTrampoline, 4);
    CopyMemory(&pSource, &stub, sizeof(stub));


    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)pSource, 6, pProtection, NULL);

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL recvHook = HookFunction(L"ws2_32.dll", "recv", &nRecv);
```

I've attached a debugger and spot an error:
**Stack around the variable pSource was corrupted.**

I couldn't really find a definitive reason for this happening, am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `GetProcAddress` returns an address. In a 64 bit world this address is going to be 64 bits. `DWORD` is 32 bits. Setting yourself up for a load of fail here, Hoss.

Comment: @user4581301 I've totally missed that, since I've replaced all others already... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This line here is copying 6 bytes of memory into a 4 byte variable

```
CopyMemory(&pSource, &stub, sizeof(stub));
```

Comment: The size of stub is 6 bytes, why would it be 4 byte variable?

Comment: @J.Doe - you are copying it to the address of pSource. pSource is a DWORD which is 4 bytes. That's why the stack is corrupted.

Comment: I'm copying it to the memory of address, not to DWORD.

Comment: pSource is a DWORD which has been allocated 4 bytes of memory on the stack. You are copying 6 bytes to that same address. That means you are filling up the 4 bytes it was allocated, and then overwriting the next 2 bytes of memory as well.

Comment: Ah! To write to mem. I should place a cast it being a pointer right? (LPVOID)pSource.

Comment: No that won't help you. pSource is still allocated on the stack, and you simply can't write to the memory outside of the 4 bytes to which it is allocated. Furthermore, you have additional problems because GetProcAddress is going to return you 8 bytes. You are then casting that to 4 bytes and then trying to overwrite it with 6 bytes.

Comment: You first should fix the size of the variable holding your proc address. It should be a QWORD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116025/discussion-between-j-doe-and-bennji-of-the-overflow).